# GCP Firewall Issue - Unable to access specific port over public internet

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, firewall, nmap

I am unable to access some specific ports in a GCP instance I created. I spin up a simple python server using command `python3 -m http.server <port#>` on port `22221` and `22222`. I can curl to both ports inside the machine or another machine inside the same VPC(using localhost or public ip). but when I tried to curl both ports from outside using public ip, only `22222` works, but the other port does not work.In the firewall I opened up all the ports.

My Firewall rule opened up all the ports
[Firewall-Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTDnb.png)

[Curl inside the machine-Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2f8c.png)

netstat
[netstat-screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeWDV.png)

**update 1 :** 
i did the same steps in AWS. Created an Ec2 -> assigned security group which allows all ports inbound/outbound -> spinup python simple http server on port `22222` and `22221`. only `22222` is accessible from public ip address. Looks like it is specific to OS(I am using ubuntu). below is the nmap from inside and outside the instance.

[nmap inside the instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6bO6.png)

[nmap from remote machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxkBN.png)

Comment: Are you sure you're using the public ip when you make the request?

Comment: yes.. i have started the server in 2 different ports and one port was accessible. i used same ip(public ip) in the curl requests.

Comment: @Alioua - added more info to Question. it may give more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Alioua - I figured it out. Your hint on `nmap` helped. It is the Firewall Issue set by my corporate network. I was testing all from a corporate network and some of the ports are blocked. I tried through my mobile LTE data and came to know it was working fine from the very beginning.

Comment: Good that help you

Answer (score 0):

It's the GCP firewall is not configured, the one shown it your screenshot, it's just to allow internal traffic in the your network (you notice that the source IP is 10.128.0.0/9), you have to add a [new firewall rule](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls)  to allow external traffic (you can set the source IP (0.0.0.0/0) if you want to let external traffic from any IP or you can specify a CIDR)

Comment: I have one firewall rule with the name `dummy` which allows all traffic from 0.0.0.0/0 and it openes all the ports - i am confused why it still does not allow external traffic for that specific port `22221`. i tried disabling the unix firewall too but it is not working. not sure what I am missing

Comment: Can you run nmap -sS -sU -Pn [external IP] for the outside network and check if the port is opened or not.

Comment: sudo nmap -sS -sU -p 22220-22222 35.237.228.241
---------------
PORT      STATE         SERVICE
22220/tcp filtered      unknown
22221/tcp filtered      unknown
22222/tcp open          easyengine
22220/udp open|filtered unknown
22221/udp open|filtered unknown
22222/udp open|filtered unknown

Comment: not sure how to format in comments - i ll try adding a screenshot